# Unable to retrieve TIFF pages from TiffBitmapDecoder.Frames -- all frames are page 1

Tags: wpf, tiff, xps, bitmapsource

I'm trying to convert a multipage tiff image into a multipage XPS document.  The problem I'm having is with the TiffBitmapDecoder and its BitmapFrames.

Here's the code:

```
private static void ToXpsDocument(string imageName, string xpsName)
{
    using (var p = Package.Open(xpsName))
    {
        PackageStore.AddPackage(new Uri("pack://thedocloljk.xps"), p);
        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(p);
        var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
        var dec = new TiffBitmapDecoder
                          (new Uri(imageName),
                          BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache,
                          BitmapCacheOption.None);

        var fd = new FixedDocument();
        foreach (var frame in dec.Frames)
        {
            var image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            image.Source = frame;
            var fp = new FixedPage();
            fp.Children.Add(image);
            fp.Width = frame.Width;
            fp.Height = frame.Height;
            var pc = new PageContent();
            (pc as IAddChild).AddChild(fp);
            fd.Pages.Add(pc);
        }
        writer.Write(fd);
        p.Flush();
        p.Close();
        PackageStore.RemovePackage(new Uri("pack://thedocloljk.xps"));
    }
}
```

This results in an XPS with the correct number of pages.  However, every page is a replica of the first page of the tiff.  In fact, if I pick out a single frame (say, dec.Frames[4]) and write it to disk, it looks like the first page.

What the heck am I doing wrong here?  Are the frames not actually the individual pages of the image?  How can I get them out and work with them???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following code (the commented lines are different than your version):

```
foreach (var frameSource in dec.Frames) // note this line
{
    var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(frameSource); // and this line
    var image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image(); 
    image.Source = frame; 
    var fp = new FixedPage(); 
    fp.Children.Add(image); 
    fp.Width = frame.Width; 
    fp.Height = frame.Height; 
    var pc = new PageContent(); 
    (pc as IAddChild).AddChild(fp); 
    fd.Pages.Add(pc); 
}
```